# auth_request doesn't work at nginx config

Tags: go, nginx, server, backend

I try in my nginx config to use the auth_request. I have an backend running on localhost:8081/welcome. It checks the token in the cookie. If the token is invalid, the server responds with 500. If it succeeds I have a 404 not found. I don't know why because on localhost:4500 is running another service.
I try to call the /protected route and get the error.

When I call /api/application everything works fine.

This is my the part of my config:

```
   location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    }
    location /api/application {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
    }
    location /protected {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
    }
    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/welcome;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions, why I get a 404 not found?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure the 404 comes from your nginx reverse proxy, not from the localhost:4500 backend?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that it comes from nginx because if I call /api/application with the same request I get the right response

Comment: But `/api/application` will be forwarded to `http://localhost:4500/api/application` while `/protected` will be forwarded to  `http://localhost:4500/protected` - so obviously different path in the backend which can explain the 404.

Comment: ahhh, okay. So how can I achieve that /protected will be forwarded to http://localhost:4500/api/application ?

Comment: Just use the right proxy_pass URL, i.e. `http://localhost:4500/api/application/`. See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem. In addition to that I have another question. Is there a way that all routes that begin with /protected/ first pass the authentication and then will be forwarded? For example http://localhost:4500/protected/application1 and http://localhost:4500/protected/application2 without specifying again auth_request /auth and so on for the specific path. Only one time for /protected/ and all paths that begin with that will first check in /protected/ and then be forwarded?

Comment: Please don't ask new question in a comment to an existing one. Nobody will expect this when searching for similar problems and only a few which might help will even see your question. Create a new post instead which contains all necessary details.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I opened a new question